# Springboot Camel context name

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Is there an easy way to give a SpringBoot Camel context a name?

In a CDI environment I can name a CamelContext:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ContextName("awesomename")
public class AwesomeRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
```

In SpringBoot it seems I have 2 options:

Either I need to either mess around with NameStrategy.

Or I need to use the @Configuration approach rather than extending SpringRouteBuilder and letting Spring create the camel context itself.

I believe giving a camel context a name is easy enough through xml configuration

What have people used to give a CamelContext a name in a Springboot environment?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the name in the `application.properties` or `application.yaml` configuration file for Spring Boot via `camel.springboot.name`, see https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot/src/main/resources/application.properties#L19

Comment: Thankyou Claus. I now realise my question is actually about trying to give a unique name to multiple camel contexts within the 1 deployable. I have 1 application.yml serving multiple SpringBoot deployables. For one of these deployables I would like to have 3 camel contexts and give these meaningful names so I can distinguish these in Hawtio. It seems the SpringBoot Camel integration provides 1 Camel context. I would like many contexts and be able to give these names. The Cdi integration provides for this with a single annotation.

Comment: That is a bad design to have many CamelContext in one app. Spring Boot is not like a normal app server that hosts X apps, its intended for 1 app only.

Comment: I disagree that multiple CamelContexts in one app (whether that be SpringBoot or CDI war/swarm) is bad design. My single CDI app is using multiple CamelContexts to poll various locations for differing source files to be transformed to a common format. I want (and get with camel-cdi) great visualisation with Hawtio about the logical grouping of the routes dealing with source locations. Dealing with the seperate locations with a different app is overkill. To do this with 1 CamelContext provides little seperation in the visualisation except for perhaps a naming convention.